# unable to change document property in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using the below google apps script code to change the document property. I have 3 different script files which connects to dev, test and live mysql database. As these google sheets gets shared with many users after successful execution in dev environment I delete the set properties section so nobody could see the connectiontring details. But the problem I run into is when I run the script that is connected to test environment has dev connectionstring in the property value. Please share me ideas to make this work for all three environments.

### File 1:

```
//
// Script file 1
// Database credentials dev
//

  dbmysqlconndev = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  dbmysqlconndev.setProperties({
   'mysqlUrl': 'jdbc:mysql://dbserverdev;databaseName=sample',
   'mysqlUser': 'username',
   'mysqlPassword': 'password'});
  var keys = dbmysqlconndev.getKeys();
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
       dbmysqlconndev.getProperty(keys[i]);
  }

  var url = dbmysqlconndev.getProperty(keys[0]);
  var user = dbmysqlconndev.getProperty(keys[1]);
  var password = dbmysqlconndev.getProperty(keys[2]);

function delProperty()
{
 var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
 userProperties.deleteProperty('mysqlUrl');
}
```

### File 2

```
//
// Script file 2
// Database credentials test
//

  dbmysqlconntest = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  dbmysqlconntest.setProperties({
   'mysqlUrl': 'jdbc:mysql://dbserverdev;databaseName=sample',
   'mysqlUser': 'username',
   'mysqlPassword': 'password'});
  var keys = dbmysqlconntest.getKeys();
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
       dbmysqlconntest.getProperty(keys[i]);
  }

  var url = dbmysqlconntest.getProperty(keys[0]);
  var user = dbmysqlconntest.getProperty(keys[1]);
  var password = dbmysqlconntest.getProperty(keys[2]);

function delProperty()
{
 var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
 userProperties.deleteProperty('mysqlUrl');
}
```

Comment: No, even though I run that function in both script files problem still persists.

Comment: Yes, Formatted the code in the original post.